# How to use "OR" in jasmine protractor inside for loop

Tags: protractor

This code fails if any of the condition is failed, I need oposite to fail if only all condition is failed

```
    var groups = utils.readGroupsFromJson("user");
    for (var i in groups)
    {
       expect(adminPage.returnAuthorized()).toContain(groups[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `toContain()` method with array to check if it contains a specific value.

```
 var groups = utils.readGroupsFromJson("user");
 expect(groups).toContain(adminPage.returnAuthorized()); // this will check whether groups array contains the value from adminPage.returnAuthorized()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this where it will check all the values and if one of them is true then it will pass but if all aren't true it will fail

```
var groups = utils.readGroupsFromJson("user");
var hasOne = false;
for (var i in groups)
{
   // If at least one is true 
   if(adminPage.indexOf(groups[i]) >= 0)
      hasOne = true;       
}
expect(hasOne).toBe(true);
```

here is a code snippet to show off the concept 
http://jsfiddle.net/bBL9P/504/